# Issue on Android while drawing custom progress bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

While drawing a custom `progress bar`, there is a little black line extending on the left out of my custom design. It looks small but easily noticeable and makes the UI look ugly/unfinished. It goes away and the progress bar looks perfect if I set left `padding` to `0dp`. But then the thumb cuts in half from left whenever it's on the start position.

How can I hide that extra black line without the thumb cutting in half?

[image]

I have a custom class where I am drawing the Thumb. I am overriding following methods in my custom class. Also it is a discrete progress bar.

```
 void drawThumb(Canvas canvas) {
    Drawable mThumb = getThumb();
    if (mThumb != null) {
        final int saveCount = canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(getPaddingLeft() - getThumbOffset(), getPaddingTop());
        mThumb.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
    }
}

 @Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    drawThumb(canvas);
}
```

Also my xml file:

```
 <com.CustomSteppingSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="12dp"
        android:minHeight="12dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_horizontal_progress_bar"
        android:thumb="@drawable/check_with_circle"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        />
```

And custom_horizontal_progress_bar.xml goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid
                android:color="@color/grayish_white" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/black" />
                <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: so what you have try for this ? please explain you code and xml file.

Comment: @sravs Please let me know if you guys need any more info. The rest of the custom class is setting progress and setting interpolator etc and has nothing to do with the design.

Comment: @kanzariya Hitesh ^^

Comment: any problem with drawable and margin can you check ?